# the import org.zkoss.zul cannot be resolved

Tags: import, zk, zul

I am using the ZK framework and I need to import this:
import org.zkoss.zul.Label;

But I keep on getting this error:
the import org.zkoss.zul cannot be resolved

I already added the zul.jar to the classpath but the error still exists. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just removed the zul.jar from the class path and added it again. It works now.